# Connecting to network drive on startup

Tags: debian, mount, systemd

I'm on Debian 8.1 and trying to mount a network drive (WD MyCloud) on startup. At first I added the following to /etc/fstab:

```
192.168.1.101/the_red_drive /media/the_red_drive cifs uid=fossi,credentials=/home/fossi/.smbcredentials
```

While this worked initially, it ended up causing interrupting the boot process and opening an emergency session. From some research I did, it seems to be caused by the command being run prior to the network being set up properly.

I then followed [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html) guide adding the following to /etc/init.d/fossi_startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          fossi_startup
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
mount -t cifs -o uid=fossi,credentials=/home/fossi/.smbcredentials \
       //192.168.1.101/the_red_drive /media/the_red_drive
```

I then ran the following commands as per guide:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/fossi_startup.sh
sudo update-rc.d fossi_startup.sh defaults 100
```

However this doesn't seem to execute or at least doesn't execute successfully. How can I run the mount on startup without interfering with the boot process?

Comment: If you are using [tag:systemd], you would use a service file, not something in `etc/init.d`. See [fstab entry for Samba share](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samba#Add_Share_to_.2Fetc.2Ffstab) or [mounting NFS share at startup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS#Mount_at_startup_via_systemd)...

Comment: @jasonwryan thanks for the links. I'll try removing the uid part from the fstab line giving the warning in your first link. If this doesn't work I'll try the systemd approach. Sorry I'm quite new to linux and not totally clear about the difference between systemd and init.d. Is the latter completely unused now in Debian 8?

Comment: There isn't a Systemd Approach  Debian 8.1 is Systemd, meaning that it's the only option...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `fstab`, as long as you mark the mount as a network one. Just add `_netdev` to the options field.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In the meantime I had other difficulties with my network drive unrelated to the question. I'll try your option once I solved the current issue. Cheers!

Comment: Excellent, this works like a charm...Thanks for that!